# Special characters not working in excel when using WEB API Media formatter

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following sample from Microsoft to create a csv formatter
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

However, despite the specified encoding, special characters like ¢ are not rendered correctly when I open the csv file in Excel. It looks OK in other applications though, including regular notepad.

```
public MyCsvFormatter(MediaTypeMapping mediaTypeMapping)
{
  MediaTypeMappings.Add(mediaTypeMapping);

  SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"));
  SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false));
  SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
}

public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
{
  Encoding effectiveEncoding = SelectCharacterEncoding(content.Headers);

  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream,effectiveEncoding))
  {
     // write content            
  }
}
```

¢ Renders as Â¢, so there seems to be an extra character in there that shows up only in excel.

Comment: Could you provide an example of generated CSV and the kind of special characters you are dealing with?

Comment: It's not clear what encoding you use on the file.  I think you should always use UTF8 to avoid issues with special/international chars.

Comment: I thought the UTF8Encoding part would specify the encoding as unicode. I tried removing iso-8859-1 and hard coding the UTF encoding, but it gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write Byte Order Mark as the very first record in your stream:

```
 byte[] BOM = new byte[] { 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf };
```

Also using UTF32 instead of UTF8 might help.

Comment: The Byte order mark seems to be the solution. It seems that you can achieve that by setting SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: true));